# why is this lua variable is nil，if the assignment statement is followed by a “,”

Tags: lua

```
local i1 = 1
print(i1)

local i2 = 1,0
print(i2)

local i3 = 1,
print(i3)
```

Result:

```
1
1
nil
```

Why i3 is nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a few exceptions, Lua ignores spaces and newlines. If you remove the newline, you have:

```
local i3 = 1, print(i3)
```

Your print is executed prior to the assignment to `i3` being executed.

According to [§3.3.3](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.3) of the Lua 5.3 manual:

> The assignment statement first evaluates all its expressions and only then the assignments are performed.

`i3` is eventually set to `1`:

```
local i1 = 1
print(i1) --Prints '1'

local i2 = 1,0
print(i2) --Prints '1'

local i3 = 5

local i3 = 1,
print(i3) --Prints '5'
print(i3) --Prints '1'
```

Comment: Also, the `i3` in the expression is not the `i3` in the `local` declaration because the declaration does not take effect until after the statement. (I think that's what @LuaTutoring's answer was getting at.)

Comment: @TomBlodget: Good point, I've updated my example to demonstrate this.

Answer (score -2):

Agreeing to **Mankarse** response, if you put a comma after a varable's content without having an ending enclosure, the system will think that the variable's content is still going and since you cannot access the variable within the variable's content, the print results in a nil. So a good way to fix it,

```
local i1 = 1
print(i1)

local i2 = 1,0
print(i2)

local i3 = 1
print(i3)
```

Just remove the `,` right after the `1`